# Can't display correct percentage value in poll

Tags: java, android, int, number-formatting

I'm trying to display a percentage in a TextView with the following code:

```
int votedTotal_int = pollObject.getList("votedBy").size();
System.out.println("Total votes cast: " + Integer.toString(votedTotal_int));

int value1_int = pollObject.getList("value1Array").size();
double value1_pct = ((value1_int / votedTotal_int) * 100);
String value1_string = String.valueOf(value1_pct);
holder.value1.setText(value1_string + " %");
System.out.println(holder.value1.getText().toString() + " votes");
```

Given that value1_int is 1, and votedTotal_int is 4, shouldn't the print out read 25.0%? So why am I getting the following?

```
07-24 16:48:21.626 13321-13321/com.test.android I/System.out: Total votes cast: 4
07-24 16:48:21.626 13321-13321/com.test.android I/System.out: 0.0 % votes
07-24 16:48:21.626 13321-13321/com.test.android I/System.out: 0.0 % votes
07-24 16:48:21.626 13321-13321/com.test.android I/System.out: 0.0 % votes
07-24 16:48:21.626 13321-13321/com.test.android I/System.out: 0.0 % votes
```

Comment: Dividing two integers will use integer division (i.e. 3/4 == 0). One could do `value1_int * 100.0 / votedTotal_int` or such.

Comment: see [Integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the below ..

```
double value1_pct = ((value1_int / votedTotal_int) * 100);
```

to

```
double value = (((double)value1_int * 100) / ((double)votedTotal_int));
```

Sample Run with `value1_int=1` and `votedTotal_int=1000 or 10000 or 100000`

```
07-24 17:09:13.904 3491-3491/? D/TEST: 0.1
07-24 17:09:30.688 3589-3589/? D/TEST: 0.01
07-24 17:09:45.366 3685-3685/? D/TEST: 0.001
```

Comment: try your code with these values `int value1_int = 1;
  int votedTotal_int = 1000;`

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer - it is wrong

Comment: Why? It works just fine.

Comment: You were lucky with your value - see my comment above - it will return an incorrect value of `0`

Comment: see either @JoopEggen comment above or the linked duplicate question

Comment: updated solution to have Scary Wombat needs also working.

Comment: Nobody has justified the change yet in writing so I just selected this one as the final answer, because it was provided first.

Comment: Dear down voter, why are you down voting when the solution is updated to handle situations which weren't handled before?

Comment: @santafebound && JRG - The comment made by JoopEggen `value1_int * 100.0 / votedTotal_int`  is a lot nicer

Answer (score 0):

```
double value1_pct = (((double)value1_int * 100) / (double)votedTotal_int);
```